# How to make dependent dropdown in excel using closedxml c#?

Tags: c#, excel, aspose, closedxml

i have one excel in which i have 3 column country , state ,city -> all having dropdown , from country selection  then related to the country state needs to display, after state selected then related to that state , city list needs to display ? i want to make excel using c# closedxml or aspose.

i have one excel in which i have 3 column country , state ,city -> all having dropdown , from country selection  then related to the country state needs to display, after state selected then related to that state , city list needs to display ? i am able to fill all dropdown list but not able to filter on the basis of selection of parent value .i am using c# closedxml or aspose.

Comment: How does the existing Excel file do it? You'll have to repeat the same with ClosedXML.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have excel with dropdown without filter , i want to filter it dynamically ,

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample code to accomplish your task. The sample code exhibits  on how to add dependent (cascading) drop down lists in Excel spreadsheet. I have used Aspose.Cells for .NET APIs. I created a new workbook from the scratch and inserted data set. I added two worksheets, i.e., "Sheet1" for storing source data and "Sheet2" for adding List data validations on A2, B2 and C2 cells. This is just an example, so please refer to it and write/update your own code accordingly.

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```cs
            // Create a new workbook object
            var workbook = new Workbook();

            // Access the worksheets collection
            var worksheets = workbook.Worksheets;

            workbook.Worksheets.Clear();

            // Create two worksheet objects
            var sheet1 = worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            var sheet2 = worksheets.Add("Sheet2");

            // Create some sample data for the three drop-down lists in sheet1
            sheet1.Cells[0, 0].PutValue("Country");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 0].PutValue("USA");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 0].PutValue("India");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 0].PutValue("England");
            
            sheet1.Cells[0, 1].PutValue("USA State");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 1].PutValue("California");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 1].PutValue("Washington");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 1].PutValue("NewYork");
            Range range1 = sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("B2:B4");
            range1.Name = "USA";

            sheet1.Cells[0, 2].PutValue("India State");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 2].PutValue("Rajasthan");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 2].PutValue("Uttar Pradesh");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 2].PutValue("Bihar");
            Range range2 = sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("C2:C4");
            range2.Name = "India";

            sheet1.Cells[0, 3].PutValue("England State");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 3].PutValue("North East");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 3].PutValue("North West");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 3].PutValue("South East");
            Range range3 = sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("D2:D4");
            range3.Name = "England";


            sheet1.Cells[0, 4].PutValue("USA California City");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 4].PutValue("Los Angeles");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 4].PutValue("San Diego");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 4].PutValue("Fresno");
            sheet1.Cells[4, 4].PutValue("San Francisco");
            Range range4 = sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("E2:E5");
            range4.Name = "California";

            sheet1.Cells[0, 5].PutValue("USA New York City");
            sheet1.Cells[1, 5].PutValue("New York City");
            sheet1.Cells[2, 5].PutValue("Baffalo");
            sheet1.Cells[3, 5].PutValue("Rochester");
            sheet1.Cells[4, 5].PutValue("Yonkers");
            Range range5 = sheet1.Cells.CreateRange("F2:F5");
            range5.Name = "NewYork";
            
            //.....
            //......
            //........


            //Enter A1 cell heading
            sheet2.Cells["A1"].PutValue("Select Country");
            // Create a cells area object for the first drop-down list in sheet2
            var area1 = CellArea.CreateCellArea(1, 0, 1, 0);
            Validation validation1 = sheet2.Validations[sheet2.Validations.Add(area1)];
            validation1.Type = ValidationType.List;
            validation1.Operator = OperatorType.Between;
            validation1.Formula1 = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4";
            validation1.ShowError = true;
            validation1.AlertStyle = ValidationAlertType.Stop;
            validation1.ErrorTitle = "Invalid value";
            validation1.ErrorMessage = "Please select a correct country value";

            //Enter B1 cell heading
            sheet2.Cells["B1"].PutValue("Select State");
            // Create a cells area object for the second drop-down list in sheet2
            var area2 = CellArea.CreateCellArea(1, 1, 1, 1);
            var validation2 = sheet2.Validations[sheet2.Validations.Add(area2)];
            validation2.Type = ValidationType.List;
            validation2.Operator = OperatorType.Between;
            validation2.Formula1 = "=INDIRECT(A2)";
            validation2.ShowError = true;
            validation2.AlertStyle = ValidationAlertType.Stop;
            validation2.ErrorTitle = "Invalid value";
            validation2.ErrorMessage = "Please select correct corresponding State";


            //Enter C1 cell heading
            sheet2.Cells["C1"].PutValue("Select City");
            // Create a cells area object for the third drop-down list in sheet2
            var area3 = CellArea.CreateCellArea(1, 2, 1, 2);
            var validation3 = sheet2.Validations[sheet2.Validations.Add(area3)];
            validation3.Type = ValidationType.List;
            validation3.Operator = OperatorType.Between;
            validation3.Formula1 = "=INDIRECT(B2)";
            validation3.ShowError = true;
            validation3.AlertStyle = ValidationAlertType.Stop;
            validation3.ErrorTitle = "Invalid value";
            validation3.ErrorMessage = "Please select correct corresponding City";

            sheet2.AutoFitColumns();
            
            // Save the workbook
            workbook.Save("g:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

You may also post your queries or comments in the dedicated [forums](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.